# How to make components explicit in what props they accept?

Tags: reactjs

Is there any known practice to make a React component constructor explicit in what arguments it accepts?

Looking at a component like below, I cannot immediately tell what do I need to pass to the constructor to initialize the component.

Instead, I need to search for specific props in the component body or check how has the component been initialized previously (if it has).

```
class MenuItem extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
         super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return <div name={this.props.name}></div>
    }
}
```

I would need something like:

```
class MenuItem extends React.Component {
         constructor(name) {...
```

Comment: React PropTypes ?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html is useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your concerns are mainly about visibility you may be better off only writing functional components which is possible since [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) do not require any class components anymore:

```
const MenuItem = ({name}) => (
    <div>{name}</div>
)
```

Buy destructuring the props in the argument list you can easily see which props are being used immediately just by looking at the function definition. From my experience writing 100's of components, functional components are usually more concise, easier to grasp and reduce boilerplate code.

Apart from that javascript is still a scripting language which means anything can be passed at runtime. [`PropTypes`](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) or using typescript may help you with auto-completion and type checking.

Answer (score 2):

There is several options to type your props.

The first one is **React PropTypes**, it works like this:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class MenuItem extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
         super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return <div name={this.props.name}></div>
    }
}

MenuItem.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}
```

You just have to write the name and types of your props inside an attribute "propTypes" of your component class.

React PropTypes is a good solution when you want to type your component props.

https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes

There is another solution, **a Javascript Flavor like Typescript**.

After setting up Typescript on your React app, you can use Typescript with your component like this:

```
interface IMenuItem {
  name: string;
}

class MenuItem extends React.Component<IMenuItem> {
     constructor(props) {
         super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return <div name={this.props.name}></div>
    }
}
```

The advantage with Typescript is that you can type every variable, every state, every props, everything !

However, this solution is expensive in time because you have to learn well Typescript and you have to type correctly every piece of your app.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html

Finally, if you just want your IDE to tells you what props you can use without typing them, you can just use object destructuring on your props with a Functional Component like this:

```
const MenuItem = ({name}) => (
    <div>{name}</div>
)
```

Hope this will help !

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly show what props your component accepts, including their types.

```
MenuItem.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string // optional string
};
```

You can even define them as required:

```
MenuItem.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired // required string
};
```

Be sure to import the library:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

- More information in the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Sinane's great answer, when using classes (without TypeScript), it is still not obvious what props are required when you read code with a large class, as the PropTypes definition has to go below the class in the code. Thus I like to add in-code comments as per below. Sure, the comments can fall out of date, so the coder has to be disciplined.

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class MenuItem extends React.Component {
    // -----   
    // Props
    // -----
    // name: PropTypes.string.isRequired 

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return <div name={this.props.name}></div>
    }
}

MenuItem.propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}
```

I also use the same comments for functional components, as the typing is missing.

```
const MenuItem = ({name}) => (
    // -----   
    // Props
    // -----
    // name: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    
    <div>{name}</div>
)
```